# Woocommerce перевести текст на русский

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно перевести текст на русский в плагине Woocommerce Dropdown Cart

код отвечающий за вывод

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-total"><?php echo $cart_contents_count.' '._n(__('item', 'woocommerce-ddc'), __('items', 'woocommerce-dc'), $cart_contents_count) ?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></a>
```

Comment: за локализацию отвечает `__('item', 'woocommerce-ddc')`, т.е. вам надо просто добавить соответствующие файлы локализации в нужном домене (woocommerce-ddc). Детали не подскажу, т.к. ни разу этим плагином не пользовался. Возможно, достаточно будет просто добавить файл `woocommerce-ddc-{$locale}.mo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо перевести слова `item* и`items`на русский,то просто поменяй 
в приведённой строке на`товар`и`товары`.

Эту строку, как я понимаю, вытащили из `woocommerce-dropdown-cart.php` - вот там и нужно заменить слова. Остальное - это уже перевод **woocommerce**.

Comment: Так и сделал, но думал может есть какой-то не такой грубый способ.
Спасибо!

Comment: Конечно, есть. Берите файл.po, переводите его с помощью poedit, скомпилированный .mo заканчивайте на сайт. Инструкций на эту тему много в Сети.